# MongoDB Schema Design on a specific Use Case

Tags: database-design, mongodb, web-applications

I am modeling my data-schema at the moment and I am not sure about if my thought-process is making sense. So I thought I might ask some of the more experienced MongoDB guys here:

---

Let us suppose my application produces **up to 10.000 event-documents a day**. I want to **access them time-based**. Like: "Give me all the events of those three days!".

My RDBMS knowledge I gathered at university first told me: "Do an Events-Collection and give each document the Event's propertie 'Date'. Done."

But then I came across with the idea to do **a collection for each day**!. Then I could access those Events very fast, by just getting all the events of one single day by just calling its coresponding collection.

Does this makes sense? Can I have hundreds/thousands collections without sacrifising speed/performance?

---

Thank you for advise :-)

Comment: this question is duplicated here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/3xMGKdIRqds

Comment: So? Can't I ask on several forums?

Comment: absolutely! just want to provide the link for anyone else who may have the same question in the future so they know where to find all the answers.

Comment: Oh you are right! Sorry. Didn't think so far :-P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

10.000 documents per day is not a very much. Over the course of one year, that is 3.65m documents. That is certainly not a very small collection, but I don't see much sense in breaking them up.

The downsides in this specific case are

- It's hard to change your query patterns later on. If you suddenly need hour-precision, you are in trouble. If you want to find all events in the last year with some field x set to y, you'll have to query 365 or 366 collections.
- Your query patterns will be more complicated, because you have to deal with the different collection names. Also, you need several round-trips to the database.
- Internationalization is very complicated, because "day" is not a well-defined point in time across the globe. Using a UTC DateTime field on the other hand allows you to query in different time zones, should that ever be required.
- Managing a large number of collections can be tedious, working with the shell will be quite annoying.
- Sharding is normally performed on a per-collection-basis. If you have many smaller collections, you can't do auto-sharding.

However, working with a larger number of collections is possible, though there are [limits you should understand.](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Using+a+Large+Number+of+Collections) As the docs explain, you can have 12,000 collections w/ one index each with the default settings. See there for more details.

Server Density blogged about their approach, they use [a lot of collections](http://blog.serverdensity.com/2010/02/28/notes-from-a-production-mongodb-deployment/) too, but they chew 650m documents and they claim that it doesn't make a big difference performance-wise.

Comment: My Application will be very read-heavy. So it can happen that I query for specific days over and over. You are saying finding all events of day X out of 4m documents is an easy task and can be performed so fast that I should not think about it any further?

Comment: Essentially, the data can be in RAM or on disk. If it's on disk, the query will take much longer. If you query the same dates over and over again, the data will be cached, so after some warm-up, requests are answered from RAM (fast). If you don't have enough RAM, you should at least have enough RAM for the indexes, so MongoDB knows *where to look*. If you use different collections, MongoDB will know where to look right away, i.e. without evaluating the index. However, the size of DateTime index should be roughly `3.6m * 2 * sizeof(DateTime)`, around 60MB, that is what you save in terms of RAM.

Comment: Thank you very much for those insights. I will mark your answer as solved after a little time. This might encourage some additional answers :-)